# Artificial Intelligence breadth-first algorithm to solve a chess game

Tags: algorithm, search, logic, artificial-intelligence

I have this question of a homework and I'm not sure about the answer. Can anyone help me with my solution, please tell me if it is correct.

Consider Deep Blue can evaluate 200 million positions a second. Assume at each move, a pawn can go to 2 possible positions, a rook 14, a knight 8, a bishop 14, a queen 28, and a king 8. Each side has 8 pawns, 2 rooks, 2 knights, 2 bishops, a queen and a king. Under standard regulations, each side makes 40 moves within the ﬁrst 2 hours (or 3 minutes a move on the average).

a) Using the breadth-ﬁrst search algorithm, how many levels can Deep Blue evaluate (visit) before each move (in 3 minutes)?

My answer:
In the breadth-first algorithm the first node is expanded first, then all the nodes generated by the first node are expanded and then their successors and so on, and if there is a solution it will find it.

The problem has 8 paws that can go to 2 possible positions, 2 hooks that can go to 14 possible positions, 2 knights that can go to 8 positions, 2 bishops that can go to 14, a queen that can go to 28 and the king that can go to 8 possible positions. It means that there are 128 possible positions:
 ((2 * 8) + (2 * 14) + (2 * 8) + (2 * 14) + (1 * 28) + (1 * 8)) = 124

There are also 2 sides with this configuration, meaning that there are 248 possible positions. This is the number of successor nodes of the root node. Each one of these nodes will have more 248 possible states and so on.

If there are 40 levels of possible positions, it means that there are 248 to the power of 40 possible positions on the three.

The software can evaluate 3 levels (248 ˆ 3) in the given time.

Comment: There are more constraints than that.  Try picking any particular position, and count the number of moves; it is generally much smaller than you estimated.  Consider the 1st move: there's only 2*8 (pawns) + 4 (knight) moves = 20, far smaller than 124; as teh game goes on, there are fewer pieces to move.  You've computed worst case for all possible moves (well, you didn't consider what happens if all pawns are queened).  If your engine explores everything, in some sense it only sees the average case :-}

Comment: Thank you. What do you mean when you say the average case? In this context it doesn't explore all the possibilities? I will talk to the professor tomorrow but the problem is described as I wrote and it assumes that each chesspiece can make those movements, that's what I understood, he didn't mentioned about the rules. I am wondering if my logical thinking is correct, I will ask him about the context of the question...

Comment: It explores all possibilities out to the frontier of the breadth first search.  (I'm going to complicate your life by bringing up the alpha-beta algorithm; you should go look this up, but given the way the prof asked the question, he likely doesn't want you take it into account).  The real question is, should estimate with the worst case, or the average case, and what are decent estimates of those numbers?  [There's no right answers here, only thoughtful ones, so the prof and I are forcing you to think.  You win.)

Comment: The fan-out (average number of branches of each node, i.e. average number of possible moves on each turn by each side) is believed to be around 40 for chess. Or more precisely, according to [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon_number), it is 35.

Comment: In middle game the number of possibilities increase. There are some pruning algorithms which help reducing branching factor. Also when checks come to play, branch factor will be less than 35 because many moves are forced, so algorithm can just follow a forced line. In endgame number of possible moves is less than average because number of pieces is less than the beginning although pieces have more freedom! That's why chess algorithms use opening books for opening and tablebases for endgame.